# JQuery this + class.animate()

Tags: jquery, html, css

How can I select a class from that object `this`?

```
$(".main-nav-a").click(function(){
   $(this).find('.sub-nav-ul').animate({height: 'toggle'});
   return false;
});
```

I have navigation with this hierarchy :

```
  <nav class="main-nav">
    <ul class="main-nav-ul">
           <li class="main-nav-li"><a href="" class="main-nav-a">Home</a>       
               <ul class="sub-nav-ul" id="sub1">
                  <li class="sub-nav-li"><a href="" class="sub-nav-a">link</a></li>
                  <li class="sub-nav-li"><a href="" class="sub-nav-a">link</a></li>
               </ul>
          </li>

    </ul>
</nav>
```

when i click on `main-nav-a` class then it show `sub-nav-ul` like slide down effect.How can I do this with Jquery?.

Comment: What do you mean by `$(this+".subclass")`?

Comment: it's unclear what you're asking...

Comment: What do you think `this + ".subclass"` would be?

Comment: `$(this).find('>.subclass')` ????

Comment: use `$(this).hasClass("subClass")`

Comment: since you're not responding, close vote to close the question...

Comment: I am really sorry for unclear question.Kindly check now i updated my question.Thank you

Comment: Which element has class `subclass`?

Comment: Agian we can't get your point

Comment: `sub-nav-ul` have class `.sub-nav-ul`.

Comment: ok i am going to write my all code.

Comment: `$(".main-nav-a > .sub-nav-ul")`?

Comment: but this is not working with me .

Comment: @Bharadwaj yes exactly .

Comment: @JqueryKing this is not working .

Comment: @Bharadwaj but on click link nothing happening.

Comment: What you tried? `$(".main-nav-a > .sub-nav-ul").click(function(){$(this).animate({height: 'toggle'});});`

Comment: I tried but only this one work for me ' $(this).siblings('.sub-nav-ul').animate({height: 'toggle'});' .Thank all of you for answering my question.Yes you have right to vote down my question because it's my mistake that i post unclear.Have a nice day everyone.:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Try :

```
$(".main-nav-a").click(function(){
   $(this).next('.sub-nav-ul').animate({height: 'toggle'});
   return false;
});
```

You were using find, that is used to select childrens. You can also use :

```
$(this).siblings('.sub-nav-ul').animate({height: 'toggle'});
```

Comment: Great ! this work for me.Thank you.I wish i can vote up but due to low low point i can't vote up.Thank you again.

Answer (score 2):

There's a mistake in your selector, you have:

```
.main-nav-a
```

But you need:

```
.main-nav a
```

Then you can use [`slideToggle`](http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/):

```
$(".main-nav a").click(function(){
    $(this).find('.sub-nav-ul').slideToggle();
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer only this work for me .I dont know why.`$(this).siblings('.sub-nav-ul').animate({height: 'toggle'});`

Answer (score 0):

```
    $(".main-nav-a").click(function(){
           $(".main-nav-a .sub-nav-ul").toggle();

        });
/*******************************************************************/

$(".main-nav-a").click(function(){
           $(".main-nav-a .sub-nav-ul").slideToggle();

        });
```